# Aligning JButton to the right

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, layout-manager

I am creating an interface in java and i want to align the button to the right. I have try but its not working. Can someone tell me how to do it?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Button_Alignment extends JFrame{
    public JPanel header,body,footer;
    public JButton add1;
    public JButton save;
    public Button_Alignment(){
        super("BUTTON");
        GridLayout g1 = new GridLayout(3,1);
        setLayout(g1);
        //////
        header = new JPanel();
        JButton add1 = new JButton("add");
        header.add(add1);
        JButton save = new JButton("save");
        header.add(save);
        //////
        add(header);
        header.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Button_Alignment ba = new Button_Alignment();
        ba.setSize(400, 400);
        ba.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current layout manager ([`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)) is being created with 3 rows and a single column.  Hence, the components you add to the `JFrame` will appear **vertically** from top to bottom.  Worse still, `GridLayout` will aportion space **equally** amongst all 3 components, meaning that your buttons will stretch in both directions, which is almost certainly **not** what you require.

I would consider using an alternative layout manager.  For simple layouts I tend to favour [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) or [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html).  For more complex layouts I lean towards [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) although there are others who prefer [`MigLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/).

More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Once you get to grips with it, GridBagLayout isn't that difficult, and offers a high degree of flexibility.  As I said though there are others who prefer MigLayout.

Comment: @Adamski..thanks dude i got it:) Thanks you all for your help:)
I have used FlowLayout and then i have aligned it to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
JButton save = new JButton ("save");
setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
add (save, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: @SoboLAN..I have try it but i do not want it like this. I want both button to be on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

A **quick and dirty** way is to put the button [*or a container immediatly wrapping the button, if you want to add other components on the right next to your button*] it in a container that uses the `BorderLayout` and use the `BorderLayout.EAST` layout constraint for that button [*or wrapping container*].

Answer (score 0):

you set `GridLayout` to the `JFrame` constructor instead of `JPanel` (JPanel has by default `FlowLayout`), I think that

```
header.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
header.add(add1);
header.add(save);
```

notice ---> but `GridLayout` in current `ComponentOrientations` to start from left to right, `then 3rd. grid is empty`

then only to add `JFrame#add(JPanel)`, in your case

```
add(header);
```